$f(x) = \sin x-x$, and $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. Solve for x.
One way to do it is just to plot the function, draw its projection about $y=x$ and find the intersections. But I've been trying to solve it more algebraically:
$$ \begin{align}
f(x) & = f^{-1}(x) \\ 
f(f(x)) & = x \\
\sin(\sin(x)-x)-\sin(x) + x & = x \\
\sin(\sin(x)-x) & = \sin(x)
\end{align} $$
Now, it is possible to just look at the equation here and see that the solution would be $x=n\pi$ where $n$ can be any integer, but that's not really rigorous, and doesn't prove that there is no other solution.
How should I proceed here?

$\sin x$ is not bijective so how do you define $f^{-1}$?

@Sahaj: That does not mean $f$ is not invertible. Perhaps something similar to this can be done to show invertibility.

You can also solve $\sin(x)-x=-x\implies \sin(x)=0$

Not only looking, but solving it can also give the result.
$$\sin(\sin x)\cos x-\sin x\cos(\sin x)=\sin x$$
$$\implies \sin(\sin x)\cot x-\cos(\sin x)=1$$
Let $\sin x=t$.
$$\cos x=\frac{1+\cos t}{\sin t}=\frac{2\cos^2\frac{t}{2}}{2\sin\frac{t}{2}\cos\frac{t}{2}}$$
$$\implies \cot x=\cot \frac{t}{2}$$
$$\implies x=nπ+\frac{t}{2}=nπ+\frac{\sin x}{2}$$
This can only be true $\forall x=nπ,n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Even simpler, $\sin(\sin(x)-x)  = \sin(x)$ gives $\sin(x)-x=2k\pi +x$ or $\sin(x)-x=(2k+1)\pi -x$.

What? It's like that? Ohh I'm sorry I though the general formula of sin had some (-1)^n somthing something. I didn't remember it well hence I did all this :")

Looking at the graph it seems that $\sin(\sin(x)-x)>0$ and $\sin(x)<0$ if $x\in((2k-1)\pi,2k\pi)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\sin(\sin(x)-x)<0$ and $\sin(x)>0$ if $x\in (2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, with equality if and only if $x=k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
And indeed, if $x\in((2k-1)\pi,2k\pi)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\sin(x)<0$ and $\sin(x)-x$ is between $-(2k-1)\pi$ and $-2k\pi$ (which follows from the fact that $\sin(x)-x$ is monotonically decreasing), which implies that $\sin(\sin(x)-x)>0$.
Analogously for the other case.
